# Build of wxWidgets app fails - undefined reference to `wxCRT_StrdupA(char const*)'

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, wxwidgets, codeblocks

I was coding a wxWidgets application many days or a week ago, and after the break returned to work today. Before the break, application built and ran successfully, but today ( without changing any code in the project ) I get this build error :

```
obj\Debug\appwx.o||In function `Z8wxStrdupPKc':|
C:\wxWidgets-3.0.1\include\wx\wxcrtbase.h|679|undefined reference to `wxCRT_StrdupA(char const*)'|
```

I am using wxWidgets 3.0.1 & CodeBlocks on a Win 7 system.
Obviously during the break I didn't touch that particular project, so the code is same. I did of course search for the solution and found [this thread](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/11374), as well as [this thread](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/15011). Reading them reminded me that I did change a compiler setting meanwhile -> -std=c++11 for gcc to follow the ISO C++11 standard. 
I unchecked that option now, but the build error remains.

**What do I need to change in the project so that it will build successfully again like it did the last time I was building it ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must recompile everything (i.e. both wxWidgets and your application) using the *same* compiler options and if you use `configure` to build wxWidgets, you also need to ensure it uses the same options as well.